# Share Variables between Build and Release pipeline in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I created two variables in Azure DevOps portal, the `MajorMinorVersion` which is Settable at the queue time and the `ProductVersion`
which value depends on the `MajorMinorVersion`. The configuration looks like this:
[image]

Is there a possibility to pass the values of those two variables to the Release pipeline, so I'm able to use them in some Agent job there?
Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found [this article](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/14515326-project-level-build-release-variables) which tells that since 2017 there is a possibility to create a variable group which can be shared across the Build and Releases pipelines.

However, I found [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/365804/allow-variables-in-variable-groups-to-be-settable.html)

> Setting the value of variables in a variable group at build queue time is not supported at the moment.

You can vote guys to add this feature to the future release of Azure DevOps [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365804/allow-variables-in-variable-groups-to-be-settable.html)